# Error passing event in handleChange on React Class Component input element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass `event.target.value` into my setState below.

I was thinking that the first event (`= event =`) would get passed in closure and be available to the return, but I get undefined when I debug that.

What is the right away to get to `event.target.value`?

```
class InputElement1CC extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputText: "",
    historyList: []
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return {
        inputText: event.target.value,
        historyList: [...previousState.historyList, event.target.value]
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="/">home</a>
        <h1>InputElement1CC - Class Component</h1>
        <input placeholder="Enter Some Text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <br />
        {this.state.inputText}
        <hr />
        <br />
        <ul>
          {this.state.historyList.map(rec => {
            return <div>{rec}</div>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InputElement1CC;
```

Comment: What does the code that calls `handleChange` look like?

Comment: I updated to include full component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value to a variable and use that variable.  Something like this:

```
 handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(
      state => ({
        inputText: value,
        historyList: [...state.historyList, value]
      }),
      () => console.log("state", this.state)
    );
  };
```

Comment: That worked.  Does ES6 give us any help on doing this? Is there a way to do it without putting in contant in the scope of that inner function?

Comment: It has to do with the way React handles SyntheticEvents. [This](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) says it all.  I guess, if you really wanted to, you could use the `nativeEvent` as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview).